# Como definir minha Primary Key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Swift` e iniciei o uso do `Core Data` recentemente.
Preciso definir qual atributo de minha entidade será a minha *primary key*. Por exemplo:

Tenho uma entidade que possui os atributos da classe:

- id
- nome
- idade

Preciso que o atributo "id" seja minha *primary key*.

Pode ser em `Objective-C` mesmo, só preciso saber como defino isso.

Answer (score 1):

//Swift

```
  class Foo: RLMObject {
        dynamic var id = 0

        override class func primaryKey() -> String {
            return "id"
        }
    }
```

//Core data

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901640/core-data-primary-key]